# Why is this compiling successfully?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, derived-class, redefinition, using-declaration

What is the reason which why this code compile :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class being {
public:
  void running(char c) {
        cout << "No one know ";
    }
};
class human :public being {
public:
    using being::running;
    void running(char y) {
        cout << "I am a human";
    }
};

int main() {
    human o;
    o.running('A');
    return 0;
}


the output : "I am a human"
```

I mean ( I am expecting having error (redefinition function in human class ))
like this :
this code compile :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class being {
public:
    int v;
};
struct human :public being {
public:
    
    double v;

};

int main() {
    human o;
    o.v = 55.2;
    return 0;
}
```

but when i add ( using being::v )

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class being {
public:
    int v;
};
struct human :public being {
public:
    using being::v;

    double v;

};

int main() {
    human o;
    o.v = 55.2;
    return 0;
}
```

the error appear:  error C2086: 'int being::v': redefinition

why this error did not appear in the first code ?

Comment: Why are you expecting that? (It isn't; the word "using" does not have its normal English meaning.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behavior of [using declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#In_class_definition).

> If the derived class already has a member with the same name, parameter list, and qualifications, the derived class member hides or overrides (doesn't conflict with) the member that is introduced from the base class.

So `human::running(char)` *hides* `being::running(char)` instead of conflict.

**EDIT**

The 2nd code snippet is ill-formed. For data members, from the standard, [[namespace.udecl]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#10):

> If a declaration named by a using-declaration that inhabits the target scope of another declaration potentially conflicts with it ([basic.scope.scope]), and either is reachable from the other, the program is ill-formed. If two declarations named by using-declarations that inhabit the same scope potentially conflict, either is reachable from the other, and they do not both declare functions or function templates, the program is ill-formed.
>
> [Example 6:
>
> ```
> ...
>
> namespace B {
>   int i;
>   ...
> }
>
> void func() {
>   int i;
>   using B::i;                           // error: conflicts
>   ...
> ...
> ```

So you can't `using` `being::v` which conflicts with `human::v`. But for member functions, [[namespace.udecl]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#11):

> The set of declarations named by a using-declarator that inhabits a class C does not include member functions and member function templates of a base class that correspond to (and thus would conflict with) a declaration of a function or function template in C.
>
> [Example 7:
>
> ```
> struct B {
>   virtual void f(int);
>   virtual void f(char);
>   void g(int);
>   void h(int);
> };
>
> struct D : B {
>   using B::f;
>   void f(int);      // OK: D​::​f(int) overrides B​::​f(int);
>
>   using B::g;
>   void g(char);     // OK
>
>   using B::h;
>   void h(int);      // OK: D​::​h(int) hides B​::​h(int)
> };
> ...
> ```

Comment: FYI the OP has updated the question, clarifying why they expected a redefinition error.

Comment: "`human::running` hides `being::running`"  Not quite.  `human::running(char)` hides `being::running(char)` but if there were any other signatures for `being::running` they would be visible as overloads of `human::running(char)`  (This is the change that `using` makes, without the using declaration, then `human::running(char)` would indeed hide all signatures of `being::running`)